Interactive checkboxes (or buttons) in subplots Matplotlib figure in QGraphicsView PyQt5
I'm trying to optimize example (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html) for my task in a small project.
I have an example that works:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
from ShortCircuitCalc.gui.windows import CustomGraphicView, MainWindow

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window(CustomGraphicView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))

        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s0 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        s1 = np.sin(4 * np.pi * t)
        s2 = np.sin(6 * np.pi * t)

        ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
        l0, = ax.plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2, color="k", label="2 Hz")
        l1, = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2, color="r", label="4 Hz")
        l2, = ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2, color="g", label="6 Hz")

        self.canvas.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

        self.lines = [l0, l1, l2]

        rax = self.canvas.figure.add_axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])

        self.labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in self.lines]
        visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in self.lines]

        self.check = CheckButtons(rax, self.labels, visibility)
        self.check.on_clicked(self.is_click)

    def is_click(self, label):
        index = self.labels.index(label)
        self.lines[index].set_visible(not self.lines[index].get_visible())
        self.canvas.draw()


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    r = Window()
    w.resultView.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    w.resultView.scene.addWidget(r.canvas)
    w.resultView.setScene(w.resultView.scene)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I get correctly next working model:

But I want to get such an active model for each subplot in my figure.
I tried to rework the above example and even got the layout I needed, but the buttons on it are not interactive. How can I refine this to get each interactive subplot. At the moment I have this code and these results:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
from ShortCircuitCalc.gui.windows import CustomGraphicView, MainWindow

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window(CustomGraphicView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        ncols = 5
        nrows = 8

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(ncols * 5, nrows * 3)))

        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s0 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        s1 = np.sin(4 * np.pi * t)
        s2 = np.sin(6 * np.pi * t)

        ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots(ncols=ncols, nrows=nrows)
        for col in range(ncols):
            for row in range(nrows):
                (l0,) = ax[row, col].plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2, color="k", label="2 Hz")
                (l1,) = ax[row, col].plot(t, s1, lw=2, color="r", label="4 Hz")
                (l2,) = ax[row, col].plot(t, s2, lw=2, color="g", label="6 Hz")
                lines = [l0, l1, l2]
                rax = ax[row, col].inset_axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
                labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
                visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
                self.check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)
                self.check.on_clicked(self.is_click)

        self.canvas.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

    def is_click(self, label):
        # index = self.labels.index(label)
        # self.lines[index].set_visible(not self.lines[index].get_visible())
        # self.canvas.draw()
        print('Button is pressed')


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    r = Window()
    w.resultView.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    w.resultView.scene.addWidget(r.canvas)
    w.resultView.setScene(w.resultView.scene)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


In my code, CustomGraphicView is just a QGraphicsView with some navigation tweaks. At the moment the implementation of CustomGraphicView and its use cases are as follows:
import sys

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavToolbar,
)
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class CustomGraphicView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self,
                 parent: QtWidgets = None,
                 figure: matplotlib.figure.Figure = None,
                 title: str = 'Viewer') -> None:
        super(CustomGraphicView, self).__init__(parent)

        self._title = title
        self._figure = figure
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()

        if parent is not None:
            self._canvas = None
        else:
            self._canvas = FigCanvas(self._figure)
            self._scene.addWidget(self._canvas)

        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setWindowTitle(self._title)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        # Start viewing position
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(1)
        self.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(1)

        self._zoom = 0
        self._mousePressed = False
        self._drag_pos = None

        self.save_model_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Save model as ...', self)
        self.save_model_action.triggered.connect(self.save_model)

        self.save_fragment_action = QtWidgets.QAction('Save fragment as ...', self)
        self.save_fragment_action.triggered.connect(self.save_fragment)

    def set_figure(self, figure):
        self._figure = figure
        self._canvas = FigCanvas(self._figure)
        self._scene.addWidget(self._canvas)
        self.setScene(self._scene)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton) -> None:

        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self._mousePressed = True
            self.viewport().setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.OpenHandCursor))
            self._drag_pos = event.pos()
            event.accept()

        else:
            super(CustomGraphicView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton) -> None:

        if self._mousePressed:
            new_pos = event.pos()
            diff = new_pos - self._drag_pos
            self._drag_pos = new_pos
            self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().value() - diff.x())
            self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value() - diff.y())
            self.viewport().setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.OpenHandCursor))

        else:
            super(CustomGraphicView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton) -> None:

        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self._mousePressed = False
            self.viewport().setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.ArrowCursor))

        super(CustomGraphicView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event: QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier.ControlModifier) -> None:

        modifiers = QtWidgets.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()

        if modifiers == QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier.ControlModifier:

            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1

            if self._zoom > -1:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

        else:
            super(CustomGraphicView, self).wheelEvent(event)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event: QtGui.QContextMenuEvent) -> None:

        # Creating context menu
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction(self.save_model_action)

        # Creating / adding separator
        separator = QtWidgets.QAction(self)
        separator.setSeparator(True)
        menu.addAction(separator)

        menu.addAction(self.save_fragment_action)
        menu.exec(event.globalPos())

    def save_model(self):
        NavToolbar.save_figure(self._figure)

    def save_fragment(self):
        rect_region = QtCore.QRect(0, 0,
                                   self.width() - self.verticalScrollBar().width(),
                                   self.height() - self.horizontalScrollBar().height())
        pixmap = self.grab(rect_region)
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save fragment as ...', 'image.png',
                                                      'Portable Network Graphics (*.png);;'
                                                      'Joint Photographic Experts Group (*.jpeg *.jpg)')[0]
        if fname:
            pixmap.save(fname)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Some figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s0 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
    s1 = np.sin(4 * np.pi * t)
    s2 = np.sin(6 * np.pi * t)

    ax.plot(t, s0, lw=2, color="k", label="2 Hz")
    ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2, color="r", label="4 Hz")
    ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2, color="g", label="6 Hz")

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = CustomGraphicView(parent=None, figure=fig)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    # Or i may
    # app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # window = CustomGraphicView(parent=None, figure=None)
    # window.set_figure(fig)
    # window.show()
    # sys.exit(app.exec_())


Your implementation is a bit odd. Most importantly, the instances of CustomGraphicsView are never actually used, only some of its components (which seem to be "extracted" arbitrarily), and that's probably the source of your issue.

This is a quick test option. When I use a CustomGraphicView as my main screen, I simply pass the figure to it on creation:
window = CustomGraphicView(None, fig, cls.tablename.title())
But when I use it as part of the main screen, the main screen is created with a CustomGraphicView with an empty scene on initialization, and then I just set the scene for it:
w = MainWindow()
w.resultView.set_figure(fig)

It makes little sense to do that, it's like building a complete house just because you need a bedroom. In any case, the check boxes appear on the plot, so it's possible that mouse events are intercepted before they could be handled. Unfortunately, your code is not reproducible as we don't have that CustomGraphivsView subclass, so please take your time to provide a proper [mre].

This issue was resolved using a dictionary and the following approach, now I get the behavior of the model that I expected.
from collections import namedtuple

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
from ShortCircuitCalc.gui.windows import CustomGraphicView, MainWindow

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window(CustomGraphicView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        ncols = 2
        nrows = 3

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(ncols * 5, nrows * 3)))

        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s0 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        s1 = np.sin(4 * np.pi * t)
        s2 = np.sin(6 * np.pi * t)

        self.ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots(ncols=ncols, nrows=nrows)
        self.checks = dict()
        for row in range(nrows):
            for col in range(ncols):
                ax = self.ax[row, col]
                # Check buttons work correctly!
                rax = self.canvas.figure.add_axes([ax.get_position().x0, ax.get_position().y0,
                                                   ax.get_position().width / 2, ax.get_position().height / 2],
                                                  frameon=False)
                # Check buttons in inserted axes is not interactive!!!
                # rax = ax.inset_axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
                (l0,) = ax.plot(t, s0, visible=False, lw=2, color="k", label="2 Hz")
                (l1,) = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2, color="r", label="4 Hz")
                (l2,) = ax.plot(t, s2, lw=2, color="g", label="6 Hz")
                lines = [l0, l1, l2]
                labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
                visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
                check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)
                check.on_clicked(lambda label, i=row, j=col: self.is_click(label, i, j))
                DictButton = namedtuple("DictButton", ["check", "lines", "labels", "visibility"])
                self.checks[row, col] = DictButton(check, lines, labels, visibility)

    def is_click(self, label, i, j):
        index = self.checks[i, j].labels.index(label)
        self.checks[i, j].lines[index].set_visible(
            not self.checks[i, j].lines[index].get_visible()
        )
        self.canvas.draw()
        print('Button is pressed')


def main():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    r = Window()
    w.resultView.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    w.resultView.scene.addWidget(r.canvas)
    w.resultView.setScene(w.resultView.scene)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

IMPORTANT NOTE!!!
Don't use checkbuttons in insert axes.
Now I get what I needed:

I am new to PyQt and matplotlib, this code is just a test version in which I tested new functionality for myself, I will be glad if these thoughts help someone else.
